# No connection between SQL Server and Homepage Server

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu-14.04, iptables

I've got a root server (Ubuntu 14.04) with a MYSQL (5.5.41) running and trying to access the database from two diffrent homepages on two diffrent server. The homepage servers use static ips. 
I set up iptables on the root.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 'my_homepage_ip' -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

If I try to access the server from the two homepages I get:
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server_ip' (111)2003.

The homepages are running on webspaces from some german provider called 1und1.

If I open the iptables and delete the reject line, everything works fine. Also I tried to access the SQL Server from my local computer which is running an XAMPP server with the same script as I use at the homepage server. This works fine.

Server('my_server') and Port (3306) are defined in my php script.

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);
```

I assume that I got wrong IPs of the homepage server or that the homepage server use an other port than 3306.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your 3rd line to `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j LOG`. This will log all attempts to the MySQL port to your `/var/log/messages` file, including the source IP address. This will allow you to verify that the source IP is the same as the IP being used for your website proper. If it is different, just change line 2 with the correct IP address.